# Write binary number to bmp image

Tags: visual-c++

I read a bmp image and store in a string vector after
converting char to number and to binary number:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
std::streampos fileSize;
std::vector<BYTE> readFile(const char* filename)
{
    // open the file:

    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);

    // get its size:
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // read the data:
    std::vector<BYTE> fileData(fileSize);
    file.read((char*) &fileData[0], fileSize);
    return fileData;
}
```

This is good for now, but I want to rewrite the bmp file after converting
 each binary number to a char and store it in a new file.

```
ofstream saveFile(path);
int i=0; string str="";
while(i<binary.size())  //the binary_size is a string that contain all binary number of bmp
    {
    str=BinartToInt(binary[i]);//BinartToInt is a function that convert 8bit binary to number
    saveFile <<str;
    i++;
    }

saveFile.close();
```

How can I  convert the vector binary string to  BMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your output stream is marked as binary too, otherwise line endings and other text processings will take effect on your  binary stream.

```
ofstream saveFile(path, std::ios::binary);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use formatted output functions to write data to binary format files.  Use `saveFile.write()`.